# Using wildcard characters while adding multi-word expressions in nltk tokenizer

Tags: python, token, nltk, tokenize

I want to tokenize the below sentences

```
"This belongs to Comp123"
"This belongs to Comp456"
"This belongs to Mech123"
```

I want to tokenize the sentences on basis of the below tokens:

```
"This belongs to Comp"
"This belongs to Mech"
```

I have the below code:

```
tokenizer = MWETokenizer()
tokenizer.add_mwe(wordpunct_tokenize("This belongs to Comp"))
tokenizer.add_mwe(wordpunct_tokenize("This belongs to Mech"))

tokens = []
for line in lines:
    tokens.append(tokenizer.tokenize(wordpunct_tokenize(line)))
```

This is not creating a Multi-word expression as a token since there is 123 and 456 appended in front of Comp and Mech which is posing an issue.
Is there a way to specify wild-card characters while adding an MWE to the tokenizer?